# Firebase, React Native: database connected but can't fetch data from firestore

Tags: database, firebase, react-native, google-cloud-firestore

I am working on a simple React Native app and need to connect to the database (in this case firebase firestore). I've tried few packages but the problem is still there. Currently I'm using firebase ^9.6.3 (modular version) > (by 'npm install --save firebase').

initialized firebase...

```
import {initializeApp} from 'firebase/app';
import {getFirestore} from 'firebase/firestore';

const firebaseConfig = {
    ...
};

const app = initializeApp(firebaseConfig);
export const db = getFirestore(app);
```

tried to get data..

```
const Firestore = () => {
  const [state, setstate] = useState('');

  const getData = async database => {
    try {
      const user = doc(database, 'testData', 'testDoc');
      const userSnap = await getDoc(user);
      const userName = userSnap.data().name;
      setstate(userName);
      return state;
    } catch (error) {
      alert(error.message);
    }
  };

  {
    useEffect(() => {
      getData(db);
    }, []);
  }

  return (
    <View>
      <Text>not showing... {state}</Text>
    </View>
  );
};

export default Firestore;
```

Though the code is fine and firebase dashboard shows the device is connected but data can't be fetched.
The alerts shows: 'Failed to get document because the client is offline.' though the internet connection is okay and I can fetch data/files from other sources.
I need help..

Comment: Hey Salman,  Did you solve your problem ?

Comment: @GökhanGeyik actually it wasn't working this way and eventually I switched to another package and luckily that worked for me.

Answer (score 1):

Can you try this:

```
const Firestore = () => {
const [state, setstate] = useState('');


useEffect(() => {
async function getData(database){
   try {
      const user = doc(database, 'testData', 'testDoc');
      const userSnap = await getDoc(user);
      const userName = userSnap.data().name;
      setstate(userName);
      return state;
    } catch (error) {
      alert(error.message);
    }
}
getData(db);
},[])

  return (
    <View>
      <Text>not showing... {state}</Text>
    </View>
  );
};

export default Firestore;
```

Comment: Unfortunately it was giving the same result.